# JSX if-else condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My simple component looks like this:

```
function Messages(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <View
        style={styles.messageWrapper}
      >
        <View style={styles.isNotMine}>
          <View
            style={styles.message}
          >
            <Text>{props.text}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.messageTime}>{props.time}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
     
      </View>
    </View>

  );
}

export default Messages;
```

I want to put some logic into JSX, but don't know how to find out more native and convenient way. I have to replace style with style called `{styles.isMine}`.

```
...
(props.isMine)? <View style={styles.isMine}> : <View style={styles.isNotMine}>  // gained error because non-closed tag
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular situation, you don't want to change the entire `View` component, but rather just the individual style, which you can do by putting the ternary expression within the `style` prop, for example:

```js
<View style={props.isMine ? styles.isMine : styles.messageInner}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `if-else` conditions to the prop, rather than the component:

```
<View styles={props.isMine ? styles.isMine : styles.isNotMine}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned 'gained error because non-closed tag'. This is happening because you can't use the ternary operator only for the opening tag. You need to use it for both together, or use a self closing tag.

Fixed v1 - Not useful because you probably want to pass child props inside the `View` component.

```
(props.isMine) ? <View style={styles.isMine}/> : <View style={styles.isNotMine}/>
```

Fixed v2 - more useful

```
(props.isMine) ? <View style={styles.isMine}> My Stuff </View> : <View style={styles.isNotMine}> Not My Stuff </View>
```

I thought I would mention this because that the root cause of your error. You seem to have already solved the problem though.